# Can't click radio button with pywinauto using UIA backend

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

On the [pywinauto documentation](http://Wrap%20a%20UIA-compatible%20Button,%20CheckBox%20or%20RadioButton%20control%20%20click()%20Click%20the%20Button%20control%20by%20using%20Invoke%20pattern) it says that you can click a radio button using the `click` method:

[image: click method documentation]

I have already had issues using the UIA backend, since it is different to win32. In this case, there seems to be no way to click a radio button.

I tried using a window specification:

```
    spec.window(auto_id='RadioButtonManualbackground').click()
```

> AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'click' were found (typo?)

It cannot find any method called `click`. I tried using `toggle` and `check` and those didn't work either.

I also tried clicking the radio button using the tree hierarchy:

```
    app.Dialog.Analysis.BackgroundCorrection.ManualBackgroundCorrection.click()
```

> pywinauto.uia_defines.NoPatternInterfaceError

Again, this didn't work with `toggle` or `check`.

**Is there support for clicking a radio button using UIA backend,** and how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bit confusing, but radio button wrapper has `.select()` method which uses `SelectionItemPattern`. I've found it in `test_radio_button` unit test.

Proper implementation should check all possible patterns and choose the working one. So I would consider it as a bug: filed [issue #549](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/549). Thanks for reporting it!

P.S. You always have method `.click_input()` as a workaround. It performs the most realistic click with moving the cursor.

Comment: I'll try the `select()` method tomorrow. Does `click_input()` use mouse coordinates? If it does then I will hesitate to use it, since my automation program is supposed to be used on a variety of resolutions

Comment: `.click_input()` uses control's rectangle middle point so this is robust to changing resolution. The only aspect that can matter: it requires active desktop so the OS shall not be locked or RDP window shall not be minimized or disconnected.

Comment: Yes! sorry, forgot to accept. I used `.select()` in the end